# Is there a way to add the total of a div?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am having trouble trying to add the total of a div from an array. I am trying to add the total miles for the input and put it in a table. I want to just add the miles together, not the flight numbers. I would also like to have an id set for it so that I can call on to the total miles in another section.

```js
var FlightNumber = new Array();
var Miles = new Array();

function insert() {
  var FlightNumberValue = document.getElementById('FlightNumber').value;
  var MilesValue = document.getElementById('Miles').value;
  FlightNumber[FlightNumber.length] = FlightNumberValue;
  Miles[Miles.length] = MilesValue;
}

function showFlightNumber() {
  var content = "<b></b><br>";
  for (var i = 0; i < FlightNumber.length; i++) {
    content += FlightNumber[i] + "<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = content;
}

function showMiles() {
  var content = "<b></b><br>";
  for (var i = 0; i < Miles.length; i++) {
    content += Miles[i] + "<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML = content;
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">

  <h1>Find out what Flight Class Member you are!</h1>
  <p>To use, please input the flight number and number of miles.
    <p>

      <br>

      <label for="FlightNumber">Flight Number</label> <input id="FlightNumber" type="text" />
      <br>

      <label for="Miles">Miles</label><input id="Miles" type="text" />
      <br>

      <br>

      <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="insert();">
      <input type="button" value="Show flight number" onclick="showFlightNumber();"> <br>
      <input type="button" value="Show miles" onclick="showMiles();"> <br>

      <hr>
</form>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Flight Number</th>
    <th>Miles</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="display">
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="display2">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <td>Total Miles:</td>
  <td></td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the miles to total by putting an id on the total column. Then I was able to use the Miles array you created and just parse the string value to an int and total those values.

Please note this code is not very clean. When you insert a new flight you should really be inserting a new row, not break lines. There are javascript frameworks out there that make it really easy to iterate over arrays, e.g. AngularJs / Angular / React / Vue.js.

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Member Info</title>
    <style> 
    table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    </style>
   <script type="text/javascript">
var FlightNumber=new Array();
var Miles=new Array();

function insert(){
    var FlightNumberValue = document.getElementById('FlightNumber').value;
    var MilesValue = document.getElementById('Miles').value;
    FlightNumber[FlightNumber.length]=FlightNumberValue;
    Miles[Miles.length]=MilesValue;
  }

function showFlightNumber() {
  var content="<b></b><br>";
  for(var i = 0; i < FlightNumber.length; i++) {
     content +=FlightNumber[i]+"<br>";
  }
   document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = content;
}

function showMiles() {
  var content="<b></b><br>";
  for(var i = 0; i < Miles.length; i++) {
     content +=Miles[i]+"<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML = content;
  // new code
  var total=0;
  for(var i = 0; i < Miles.length; i++) {
     total += Number.parseInt(Miles[i]);
  }
  document.getElementById('total-miles').innerHTML = total;
}

</script>
    </head>
        <body>

        <form id="form">

            <h1>Find out what Flight Class Member you are!</h1>
            <p>To use, please input the flight number and number of miles.<p>
        
        <br>

            <label for="FlightNumber">Flight Number</label> <input id="FlightNumber" type="text" /> 
        <br>

            <label for="Miles">Miles</label><input id="Miles" type="text" />
        <br>

        <br>

            <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="insert();">
            <input type="button" value="Show flight number" onclick="showFlightNumber();"> <br>
            <input type="button" value="Show miles" onclick="showMiles();"> <br>

        <hr>
        </form>

        <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                  <th>Flight Number</th>
                  <th>Miles</th> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><div id="display">
                    </div></td>
                  <td><div id="display2">
                    </div></td> 
                </tr>
                    <td>Total Miles:</td>
                    <td id="total-miles"></td>
              </table>
        </body>

</html>
```

Comment: is there any way to use the id= "total" to highlight as well? Like if I wanted to add a table like this and highlight the correct answer with the corresponding color?<table id="MemberTable" style="width:100%", border="1px solid black"> <tr> <td>Bronze Member</td> <td><10000 miles flown</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Silver Member</td> <td><25000 miles flown</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Gold Member</td> <td>>25000 miles flown</td> </tr> </table>

Comment: you can use a css id selector. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_id.asp